# Issue reading ConnectionString in nopCommerce

Tags: .net, database, nopcommerce

I added connection string in web.config

`<ConnectionStrings> <add name="DB1" connectionString="server=1.12.123.1234;database=database1;allowuservariables=True;user id=remoteUser;password=tmppassword123;" /> <add name="DB2" connectionString="server=localhost;database=carpartstore;allowuservariables=True;user id=root;password=tmppassword123;"/> </ConnectionStrings>`

And in HomeController.cs :

`public static string conSTring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB1"].ConnectionString;`

but conSTring is NULL and creates exception when I try to create MYSQLCONNECTION.

It is however picking some connectionString but its not what's in config.

[image]

**What am I missing here?**

I want to read DB connection string in Homecontroller but it reading

Comment: I also tried with local host instead of IP address for connect database but it still not work

Comment: nopCommerce connection strings are in the file, `\Presentation\Nop.Web\App_Data\appsettings.json"

Comment: [nopCommerce intro](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/developer/tutorials/instruction-on-how-to-start-developing-on-nopcommerce.html)